# Is there a way to pas rvalue reference of some unique_ptr to thread pool

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using C++11 (I can't use newer C++'s standards).
I can't pass a function with rvalue reference of unique_ptr to my thread pool.

Here is a simple code.

Working with `test2` function and not working with `test1`.

```
#include "thread-pool.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Mystruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    std::string c;
};

void test1(int id, std::unique_ptr<Mystruct>&& ms, int a)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << ms->c << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(a));
    }
}

void test2(int id, std::string&& c, int a)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(a));
    }
}

int main()
{
    ctpl::thread_pool p(10);
    Mystruct* ms = new Mystruct;
    std::unique_ptr<Mystruct> msp(ms);
    p.push(test1, msp, 10);
    p.push(test2, "this is the end", 10);
    p.push(test2, "hello from the other side", 5);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
no instance of overloaded function "ctpl::thread_pool::push" matches the argument list
```

```
C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'std::future<unknown-type> ctpl::thread_pool::push(F &&,Rest &&...)'
```

```
C2780   'std::future<unknown-type> ctpl::thread_pool::push(F &&)': expects 1 arguments - 3 provided
```

```
C2672   'ctpl::thread_pool::push': no matching overloaded function found
```

I am using [vit vit repository](https://github.com/vit-vit/CTPL) for my thread pool implementations.I am using this link for [thread pool](https://github.com/vit-vit/CTPL/blob/master/ctpl_stl.h) implementation for my `thread-pool.hpp` file.

I can't change my `test1`'s function arguments due i am using another API.
Is there a way to pass this function to my thread pool object or another implementation of thread pool.

Comment: Why would anyone ever want to pass r-value-references like this? This usage doesn't make any sense. If you want to pass data by reference to a thread then utilize `std::ref` or `std::cref`.

Comment: I am trying to change `p.push(test1, msp, 10);` to `p.push(test1, std::cref(msp), 10);` but it's not working yet. I am using `std::move` or other solutions i saw before but they didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pas rvalue reference of some unique_ptr to thread pool

You should not do this. Passing an rvalue reference suggests the function takes ownership of the pointer; The correct way to signal "takes ownership" in the function signature is to take the parameter by value:

```
void test1(int id, std::unique_ptr<Mystruct> ms, int a) // << receive ms by value
{
    // ...
}
```

and use std::move in client code to pass the argument:

```
std::unique_ptr<Mystruct> msp(ms);
p.push(test1, std::move(msp), 10);
```

or:

```
p.push(test1, std::make_unique<Mystruct>(ms), 10);
```

Comment: As i mentioned in question i can't change `test1` arguments. i am using a library for my udp server. i receive my message with type of `std::unique_ptr<udp_message>&& msg`
another thing that i tried both of your methods but they didn't work. i get some errors.

Comment: @MHAlikhani then you don't run this function directly from a different thread. Instead you should trigger an unrelated function/lambda that triggers the test

Comment: You mean that i should not pass test1 function to my threadpool?